# Interim Report in mssql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with the data. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5jjA.png)
How can I get the amount of "discount" column for the values in those cells where the values in the column "by_recomended" the same?
(summ by discount) where value in by_recomended the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select by_recomended, sum(discount)
from your_table
group by by_recomended
```